# webkitnotifications not defined on one machine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We are working on a webapp for chrome. We use this browser for the rich notifications and today we had a "FML" kind of a problem.

One of the customers rang us about having problem with log-in to the webapp. His Google Chrome Browser couldn't find `webkitNotifications`. And the problem is, on other Google Chrome Browsers it works.

How should i face this problem? We tried to re-install chrome manually (via. *Team Viewer*). We deleted old settings, files etc. but still we face the same issue.

EDIT: Ok. We found out that the update 35.0.1916.114 made this mess. I don't like the idea to wait for the Google to repair the issue so I'm asking desperately - what can i do in this case (ofcourse I'm aware of the posibility to rebuild the whole notification system but I don't want to do this...)?

Comment: Are notification so desperately needed? Can you leave them out for browser that don't support them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884596/webkitnotifications-deprecated-in-chrome-version-35-0-1916-114-m

Comment: Yes. They are. The anwser to this issues is that google changed the notifications (again btw), and we had to get back to the old version.