# webkitnotifications deprecated in Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, webkit-notifications

I just see that `window.webkitnotifications` is no more available in **Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m**.

Is it your case also ?

Comment: Try using the new Notification API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Web_Notifications

Comment: Thanks i will use it instead !

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little fallback for the notifications API. I should fix it up a little bit further on.

https://github.com/wondrme/baloon